# How to customize normalize.css font size?

Tags: html, css, normalization

It's not i'm stupid or something (or maybe I am :o), how do I change the font size for normalize.css? It's too big for the layout I'm making and I've seen they're using **percentage** for the font size. Will changing the font-size of `html` directly affect the font-sizes of all  child elements or I'd have to calculate too to decrease the font-size of all the other elements?

**EDIT**: [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/2.0.1/normalize.css) is over here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using relative font sizes (`ems`), then if you change the font size of the parent, then children will be scaled accordingly.

Comment: lowering the percentage of `html` didn't work. You can see the [css here](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/2.0.1/normalize.css).

Comment: @Severus, Huh?  Set a pixel size on `body`, and then `ems` size for your other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `font-size` where the `font-family` is defined for `html`.

Answer (score 0):

You could change this line:

```
font-family: sans-serif; /* 1 */
```

…to something like this:

```
font: normal 12px/1.5 sans-serif; /* 1 */
```

The rest should scale accordingly.